# TypedFactoryFacility: Passing null argument

Tags: castle-windsor

Consider the following test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Create_ServiceWithDynamicDependency_Created()
    {
        // arrange
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(Component.For<IServiceFactory>().AsFactory());

        container.Register(Component.For<ServiceWithDynamicDependency>().LifeStyle.Transient);
        container.Register(Component.For<SomethingStatic>().LifeStyle.Transient);

        var factory = container.Resolve<IServiceFactory>();

        // act
        ServiceWithDynamicDependency serviceWithDynamicDependency = factory.Create(null);

        // assert
        Assert.That(serviceWithDynamicDependency, Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

This fails with the following exception: Could not resolve non-optional dependency for 'Testing.Windsor.Factory.ServiceWithDynamicDependency' (Testing.Windsor.Factory.ServiceWithDynamicDependency). Parameter 'somethingDynamic' type 'System.String'

If I replace the assert part with this:

```
        ServiceWithDynamicDependency serviceWithDynamicDependency = factory.Create("foo");
```

The component is resolved as expected. Does anyone know of a workaround for this or do I have to hand-roll factories which accepts null arguments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although you didn't specify it I'm assuming your component has one constructor that looks like this:

```
public ServiceWithDynamicDependency(string somethingDynamic) {}
```

The behavior you're observing is not a bug - this is by design, and here's why.

If a value is required an actual value has to be provided, and `null` is not considered to be a correct value. Otherwise Windsor would just be passing `null` in for every constructor instead of bothering to find actual dependencies for that.

`null` is a special value in .NET and it means "no value". So even though you explicitly provide `null` as an argument Windsor will ignore it.

To solve this, instead of working around be explicit that the value is optional and provide a second constructor that does not include it.

Windsor is smart enough to pick the right constructor and if the value is not provided (or null as in your case) it will pick the no-argument constructor, and when the value is there (is not null) it will pick the one with the value.